# tcolorbox: title within the box and without a colon

Tags: titles, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create my theorems using tcolorbox, where the title is inside the box and there isn't a colon after the title.

I use `style=plain` so the title isn't on top of the box, but that automatically add a colon after the theorem number, which I don't want.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem{bth}{Theoreme}
{colback=red!20,colframe=red,theorem style=plain,fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{bth}{}{}
This is a theorem with the title right in front.
\end{bth}

\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

Is there a way to remove that colon? Or at least change it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at section 18.2 of [`tcolorbox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)'s documentation. There, you will find a desctiption of two options:

> /tcb/terminator sign=⟨sign⟩
> (no default, initially empty)
>
> The given ⟨sign⟩ is used as terminator at the end of the title text of a theorem.

> /tcb/terminator sign none
> (style, no value)
>
> Sets /tcb/terminator sign→ P. 368 to the default empty text.

So you probably want something of the sort:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem{bth}{Theoreme}
{colback=red!20,colframe=red,theorem style=plain,fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,terminator sign none}{th}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{bth}{}{}
        This is a theorem with the title right in front.
    \end{bth}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had tried separator sign none, which didn't work, and didn't think to look further.

Comment: @AO3userwithoutCSSknowledge, Happened to me as well... :)